# How to align text to RadioListTile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a text followed by several RadioListTile. I would like to have the text aligned to the start of the radio buttons, but I don't know what's the best way to do it that will work on all screens.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

This is my code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<Question>(
          future: futureQuestion,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      snapshot.data.body,
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: [
                        for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.data.answers.length; ++i)
                          RadioListTile<int>(
                            title: Text(snapshot.data.answers[i]),
                            value: i,
                            groupValue: _selectedAnswer,
                            onChanged: (int value) {
                              setState(() {
                                _selectedAnswer = value;
                              });
                            },
                          )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
            }

            // By default, show a loading spinner.
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use `ListTileControlAffinity`

```
 RadioListTile(
    value: 0,
    groupValue: 1,
    onChanged: (v) {},
    title: Text("Test string"),
    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
 )
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I don't want to put the radios on the right though...

Answer (score -1):

change the alignment to start

```
Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          snapshot.data.body,
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.data.answers.length; ++i)
              RadioListTile<int>(
                title: Text(snapshot.data.answers[i]),
                value: i,
                groupValue: _selectedAnswer,
                onChanged: (int value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedAnswer = value;
                  });
                },
              )
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: are you trying to change the alignment of the title text for the radio button or the whole RadioListTile?

Comment: I changed the same line as you did, the one that belongs to the inner column.

Comment: It still doesn't align the text correctly. Did you test it?

Comment: I have no problem when testing it here:
http://prntscr.com/13gns8w